# Cant checkout from WebSVN

Tags: svn

I am trying to download a script from SVN. The url looks like this:

http://websvn.myurl.com/list.php?repname=name_1

I am trying to download using:

```
svn checkout --username myuser --password mypass "http://websvn.myurl.com/list.php?repname=name_1"
```

I got "URL is not properly URI-encoded", then I changed the "?" for "%3F", and the output shows:

```
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://websvn.myurl.com/list.php%3Frepname=name_1': 200 OK (http://websvn.myurl.com/)
```

But nothing gets downloaded.

Sorry I can't post the real URL, but it's a private project and I don't have anyone else online to ask.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid, but **you can not predict URL** of repo from WebSVN URL and must ask owner, admin, PM "Which URL for checkout I have to use"

And problem is not only format of URL, but even host- and path-names!

### Sample from my WebSVN (lazy install, without multiviews)

- WebSVN URL of repo1 http://mayorat.e-city.net.ru/websvn/listing.php?repname=Hello+World
- WebSVN URL of repo2 http://mayorat.e-city.net.ru/websvn/listing.php?repname=GreyLink+CustomLocations
- Repo1 URL http://mayorat.e-city.net.ru:8088/svn/Hello/
- Repo2 URL https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/customlocations-greylink/

Surprise!!!

1. Traling part of path in WebSVN is free-form **repository label**, not directory name
2. WebSVN can handle both local and remote repository under own namespace

Answer (score 0):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450352/cant-checkout-sources-using-tortoisesvn/5450699#5450699) on stackoverflow. In short: You cannot use svn tools with fancy svn web browser interfaces, only the svn DAV interface will work. The latter looks rather ugly and will only display the latest revision in a web browser. So you need to change the URL.